# NullPointerException when call a method from BroadcastReceiver to Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-broadcast

**Edit 1**

I need to call a method from BroadcastReceiver and method exist in the Activity class mention below.

I tried this code and got `NULL_POINTER_EXCEPTION` where I create the reference the MainActivity class.

Correct me what I'm doing wrong ?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void myTesting(){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome to Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

**BroadcastReceiver.java**

```
public class BootCompeteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public Context mContext;
private MainActivity mainActivity;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mContext = context;

    try {
        mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        mainActivity.myTesting();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Activity is not a good place to write a method which you are going to call from another resources. So move the method `myTesting` into some uitility classes..

Comment: and creating an instance of activity class is not good as activity has its lifycycle and is started by startActivity(intent)

Comment: **"mainActivity = new MainActivity();"** You can NOT create an instance of an `Activity` class using `new`. It quite simply will not work.

Comment: I can understand but this time I need to use method from Activity class @PankajKumar

Comment: Is there is any another way to do this thing... @Raghunandan

Comment: @Squonk : what should create the instance of the an `Activity` for this?

Comment: An Activity shouldn't be started from a BroadcastReceiver or a Service. As you don't explain what the method is supposed to do (your example only has it showing a Toast) then it's difficult to advise further.

Comment: For the demo, I am using only Toast in that method. @Squonk

Answer (score 0):

Do something like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

try {

    MainActivity.this.myTesting();

} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   IntentFilter intFilt = new IntentFilter(Constants.YOUR_BROADCAST_RECEIVER_ACTION);
   registerReceiver(receiver, intFilt);

}

public void myTesting(){
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome to Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);

}
}
```

Comment: So what is going to start the Activity to allow it to create and register the BroadcastReceiver? The OP is listening for ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED as far as I can tell from the receiver's class name.

Answer (score 0):

You can `startActivity` in `onReceive`, and call `myTesting` in `onCreate` of your Activity.

Comment: Do I call what I mention in the example ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static volatile int INSTANCE_COUNTER = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        INSTANCE_COUNTER++;

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.your.package.ACTION");
        registerReceiver(mWhateverReceiver, intentFilter);

        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("fromYourReceiver", false)) {
            myTesting();
        }
    }

    private void myTesting() {
        // Do something here
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mWhateverReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            myTesting();
        }
    };

    public static boolean isInstanceExist() {
        return INSTANCE_COUNTER > 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();

        INSTANCE_COUNTER--;
        unregisterReceiver(mWhateverReceiver);
    }
}
```

Your receiver

```
public class BootCompeteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (MainActivity.isInstanceExist()) {
            // There is already one instance of MainActivity, so broadcast this
            // event to trigger the receiver inside MainActivity to do your task
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("com.your.package.ACTION");
            context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        } else {
            // There is no instances of MainActivity exist, so start a new one
            // with the action that let the instance know what it should do
            Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            activityIntent.putExtra("fromYourReceiver", true);
            activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(activityIntent);
        }
    }
}
```